# Have flexbox fill up vertical space, but also expand if it needs to

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**I need flexbox** to fill up the vertical space, depending on the browser site, I got help with that. I found a new issue today that I have no clue how to solve. If I get too much information in the content region on the site, I need the page to expand. It works fine if I remove flexbox from the body, but then it does not fill up the vertical space.

So I'm still thinking that I should use flexbox, but not sure how to solve it, and if it is the correct way. Does anyone have any tips to solve this?

As I said, I tried removing the flexbox, but that ruins my other setup, and also I tried to split up the "regions" in the code, but that made the syntax way too messy.

problem: if I get too much information(such as inputbars or images or things like that) the site does not expand.Since it is set to fill the vertical size. I need it to expand. Both the Blue side menu and the white content box should expand at the same height.

CodePen:(there is commented out code in this one, that shows the site get squished)
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJwOqa?editors=1100

Thanks for the help :)

HTML CODE

```
      <!--__________HEADER_________-->
  <section id="header">
          <div class="adminTitle"><h5>HEADER</h5></div>
  </section>
  <!--__________CONTENT_________-->
  <section id="main">
        <div id="sideMenu">
          <div id="sideMenuInner">
            <div class="sideMenuOption"><h5>Option One</h5></div>
            <div class="sideMenuOption"><h5>Option Two</h5></div>
            <div class="sideMenuOption"><h5>Option Three</h5></div>
            <div class="sideMenuOption"><h5>Option Four</h5></div>
            <div class="sideMenuOption"><h5>Option Five</h5></div>
            <div class="sideMenuOption"><h5>Option Six</h5></div>
            <div class="sideMenuOption"><h5>Option Seven</h5></div>
            <div class="sideMenuOption"><h5>Option Eigth</h5></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentContainer">
          <div id="ribbon">
            <div id="ribbonInner">
              <div class="ribbonTitle"><h4>Option Two</h4></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="content">
            <div id="contentInner">
              <div class="adminInputInner">
                <label for="fullname" class="adminLabel">Email</label>
                <input class="adminInputField" type="text">
              </div>
              <div class="adminInputInner">
                <label for="fullname" class="adminLabel">Full name</label>
                <input class="adminInputField" type="text">
              </div>
              <div class="adminInputInner">
                <label for="fullname" class="adminLabel">Password</label>
                <input class="adminInputField" type="text">
              </div>
              <!-- REMOVE COMMENT TO SEE THE SITE GET SQUISHED 
              <div class="adminInputInner">
                <label for="fullname" class="adminLabel">More input</label>
                <input class="adminInputField" type="text">
              </div>
              <div class="adminInputInner">
                <label for="fullname" class="adminLabel">Even more input</label>
                <input class="adminInputField" type="text">
              </div>
              <div class="adminInputInner">
                <label for="fullname" class="adminLabel">Some more input</label>
                <input class="adminInputField" type="text">
              </div>
              -->
              <div class="adminInputInner">
                <button class="adminBtn">Exicute option two</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
  <!--__________FOOTER_________-->
      <section id="footer">
        <div id="footerInner">
          <div id="footerTextOne" class="footerText"><a><h5>Rules</h5></a></div>
          <div id="footerTextTwo" class="footerText"><a><h5>Footer Policy</h5></a></div>
          <div id="footerTextThree" class="footerText"><a><h5>&copy; Footer 2017</h5></a></div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

CSS CODE

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }

  body {
    min-height:100vh;
    margin:0;
    background-color: #efefef;
    font-family: "Poppins";
    color: white;
  }

  html {
    height:100%;
  }

  html,body {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }

  /*________HEADER_______*/

  #header {
    background-color: #151515;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    color: white;
  }

  /*_________CONTENT_________*/

  #main {
    flex:1;
    display:flex;
  }

  #contentContainer {
    flex: 4;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  #sideMenu {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    width:250px;
    background-color: #3786c8;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  }

  #sideMenuInner {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .sideMenuOption {
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .sideMenuOption:hover{
    background-color: #4394d8;
  }

  #ribbon {
    background-color: white;
    flex: 1;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
  }

  #ribbonInner{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }

  .ribbonTitle {
    color: #151515;
    margin: auto auto auto 10px;
  }

  #content {
    background-color: white;
    flex: 8;
    display: flex;
  }

  #contentInner{
    display: flex;
    flex: .5;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .adminInputInner{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .adminLabel{
    color: #151515;
  }

  .adminInputField{
    border: solid gray 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin: 10px;
  }

  .adminLabel{
    color: #151515;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  }

  .adminBtn{
    background: linear-gradient(141deg, #0fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px 15px;
    margin: 10px;
  }

  /*_______FOOTER_______*/

  #footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #151515;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  #footerInner{
    display: flex;
    color: white;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .footerText{
    margin: 0em 1em;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: [https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/](https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/)

Comment: I noticed after my answer on your previous question, you don't accept any of your question's answers. You are suppose to, to mark quality content, and as you didn't respond to my comment I guess the answers helped. Accept will also attract more experienced users pay attention to your future questions.

Comment: Sorry dude, i'm new to this site, I did not see your answer on my prev. post. But I accepted the one I got the most out of. Thanks for the link, and the advice :)